# Hacer join en criteria builder pero en una de las entidades no usar el id, sino otra columna

Tags: criteria

Esto es lo que quiero lograr:

```
select u1_0.* 
from public.user u1_0 join public.client c1_0 on **u1_0.clientcode** =c1_0.code where 1=1 and 1=1 and c1_0.platform=0;
```

Esto es lo que me genera con criteria builder

```
select u1_0.* 
from public.user u1_0 join public.client c1_0 on **u1_0.id** =c1_0.code where 1=1 and 1=1 and c1_0.platform=0;
```